# how to use sharedpreferences to change language

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have button to choose between two languages in the **SettingsActivity** it works with out problems in this activity only but I can't change language for other activities.
***I want that when I choose a language the application restart and change language for all other activities***, 
how can to do this?
I tried to make method **loadLocalLanguage** in every other activity and call it in **onCreate** before ***setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);*** but it doesn't seem to be a good idea and it made the Application crash:

```
 private void loadLocalLanguage(){
        SettingsActivity settingsActivity = new SettingsActivity();
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String lang = mPreferences.getString("My_Language", "");
        settingsActivity.setLocal(lang);
    }
```

here is my **SettingActivity**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout btnLanguage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLocal();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        btnLanguage = findViewById(R.id.btn_language);

        btnLanguage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showLanguageDialoge();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showLanguageDialoge() {
        final String listItems[] = {"English", "العربية"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    setLocal("en");
                    recreate();
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    setLocal("ar");
                    recreate();
                }
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void setLocal(String lang) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("My_Language", lang);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void getLocal() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = sharedPreferences.getString("My_Language", "");
        setLocal(language);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you just let the system settings handle the language?

Comment: I want to allow user to change language by himself if he want to.

Comment: yes, they can do that in the settings of the phone, you don't have to offer that in your app

Comment: you can also manage it with Locale,  why to use preference?

Comment: I know that put this is task from my Internship program and I want to know how to solve it.

Comment: I used preference to safe chosen language when user close the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in onResume:

```
Locale locale = "LOADYOURLANGUAGE";
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it in onResume in MainActivity and it works the same as I wanted, Thank you so much Andrea.